# Include IF statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have written the script below with some help. I am now trying to combine with an IF Statement. Here is what I am trying to accomplish, if `%%GLOBAL_Availability%%`is empty, then do not display the button. Else, display the button and run the script.

I did some research and came up with the below:

```
           if (%%GLOBAL_Availability%% ==""){

            <div><input id="ShopButton" style="display: none";></div> 

            }

            else {

            <!--Amazon Shopping button-->
       <div><input id="ShopButton" </div>

<script>


document.querySelector("#ShopButton").addEventListener("click",function(){
    window.location.href='%%GLOBAL_Availability%%';
},false);

</script>

            }
```

It did not work at all. I am VB.net, and just learning this hard way.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot use Javascript *outside* of `<script>`, and you cannot use html *inside* `<script>`. Also your html is invalid since your input tag is not closed and missing the `type` attribute: `<div><input id="ShopButton" </div>`. I recommend you google for `document.createElement`, or, maybe much easier for you, learn some basic DOM manipulation with jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that your variable %%GLOBAL_AVAILABILITY%% is a string since you're testing that it's empty via testing that it's equal to a blank string.

In javascript I'd offer 2 tips for testing if a string exists or is empty.

1 - use the .length property of the String object.

2 - to check that it exists check that the type of %%GLOBAL_AVAILABILITY%% is a string use the identity operator === to check that the variable is of type string.

Your if statement should look like the below:

```
if(typeof %%GLOBAL_AVAILABILITY%% === typeof string && %%GLOBAL_AVAILABILITY%%.length > 0){
 //execute code
}
```

Secondly, javascript is made to manipulate the DOM, so there's no need to insert new HTML based on a condition, you can just manipulate the properties of the existing HTML - in this case, setting the display property of '#ShopButton' to none.This can be achieved like this:

```
document.getElementById('ShopButton').style.display = "none";
```

So, your code should look like this:

```
if(typeof %%GLOBAL_AVAILABILITY%% === typeof string && %%GLOBAL_AVAILABILITY%%.length > 0){
     document.getElementById('ShopButton').style.display = "none";
} else{
    document.getElementById('ShopButton').style.display = ""; //MAKE VISIBLE
    document.getQuerySelector('#ShopButton').addEventListener('click', function(){
        document.location.href = '%%GLOBAL_AVAILABILITY%%';
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am still getting my feet wet, so this was very constructive.

Comment: Of course, I would highly recommend jQuery for beginning javascript programmers because it drastically simplifies the work required to do these types of operations. As a rule of thumb, your javascript will be cleaner if you move it out of script tags and into it's own file. Also, in jQuery you can store HTML in strings and append or detach the HTML to your document as needed, which may have been something I missed in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want the input to be "display: none;" if the variable is empty, in which case you can just change the style attribute based on the variable. Something like:

```
<div><input id="ShopButton" style="display: none";></div>
<script>
if (%%GLOBAL_Availability%% == "") {
    document.getElementById("ShopButton").style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector("#ShopButton").addEventListener("click",function(){
      window.location.href='%%GLOBAL_Availability%%';
    },false);
}
</script>
```

This will simply render the element as invisible and then the script will make it visible if the variable isn't empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <input id="ShopButton" style="display: none";>
</div>

<script>
    if (%%GLOBAL_Availability%% == "") {
        document.getElementById("ShopButton").style.display = "block";
        document.querySelector("#ShopButton").addEventListener("click",function(){
        window.location.href='%%GLOBAL_Availability%%';
        },false);
    }
</script>
```

Is this what you're trying to do maybe?